# Средство прокетирования серверных

Tags: сервер

Господа,

подскажите ***бесплатное*** средство проектирования/рисования серверных шкафов и стоек?А также бесплатные аналоги nanoCAD СКС, если конечно такие существуют.

Comment: Не уловил... Вы ищете визуальный редактор для расчета емкости/питания/охлаждения/........./количества_уборщиц ЦОД? Или как лучше разместить в стойку/шкаф несколько серверов/свичей/розеток? :)

Comment: Второй вариант. Для графического представления размещения оборудования в шкафу. Но буду  также признателен если так же укажете ПО, описанное вами в первом вопросе.